# Binary operator '~=' cannot be applied to two 'Optional<Error>' operands

Tags: swift

I have `ClassError` enum as follows, and one of them can return the error message `ExportError(Error)` and the other one just the name. I wonder how to get the error message in `switch case` and print it out.

I am getting the following error

> Binary operator '~=' cannot be applied to two 'Optional'
> operands

**ClassError.swift**

```
enum ClassError: Error {
  case PathIsInvalid
  case ExportError(Error)
}
```

**ClassViewController.swift**

```
dataExport { [weak self] (data, error) in
  if error != nil {
    switch error as? ClassError {
    case .PathIsInvalid:
      print("path is not valid")
    //Getting error in the following line
    case .ExportError(error):
      print ("Error :", error )
    case .none:
      print(error)
    }
  }
  
  if let data = data {
    self?.dataAnalysis(data)
  }
}

private func dataExport(completion: @escaping([[String]]?,Error?) -> ()) {
 do {
  let data = try classVM.exportData()
  completion(data, nil)
 } catch {
   completion(nil, error)
 }
}
```

**ClassVM.swift**

```
func exportData() throws -> [[String]] {
    guard let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: type ) 
    else { throw ClassError.PathIsInvalid }
    do {
      return try ExcelReader().readExcel(filePath: filepath)
    } catch {
      throw ClassError.ExportError(error)
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the word `error` actually refers to the *parameter* `error`, rather than a new variable:

```
case .ExportError(error):
```

So you are essentially saying:

```
// code for illustration purposes only, not supposed to work
(error as? ClassError) == .some(.ExportError(error))
```

Note that the two occurrences of `error` refers to the same thing. That's probably not what you meant, but the compiler thinks that *is* what you meant, and tries to pattern match the associated value of `ExportError` against `error` using the `~=` operator, as `error` here is considered an [expression pattern](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#ID426)

However, both operands are of type `Optional<Error>`. The `~=` operator on `Optional<Wrapped>` requires that `Wrapped` conforms to `Equatable`, but `Error` does not conform to `Equatable` as it is a protocol. Hence the error message.

You probably meant to introduce a new identifier, so you should use a binding pattern, rather than just an expression pattern.

```
case .ExportError(let exportError):
    print("Error :", exportError)
```